# Type Class Derivation accessing default values

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-macros, scala-3, generic-derivation

Is there a clean way to access the default values of a case class fields when performing type class derivation in Scala 3 using Mirrors? For example:

```
case class Foo(s: String = "bar", i: Int, d: Double = Math.PI)
```

`Mirror.Product.MirroredElemLabels` will be set to `("s", "i", "d")`. Is there anything like: `(Some["bar"], None, Some[3.141592653589793])`?

If not could this be achieved using Macros? Can I use the Mirrors and Macros simultaneously to derive a type class instance?

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: I don't know what I was drinking. There is no discussion on that sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to write a macro working with methods named like `<init>$default$1`, `<init>$default$2`, ... in companion object

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def printDefaults[T]: Unit = ${printDefaultsImpl[T]}

def printDefaultsImpl[T](using Quotes, Type[T]): Expr[Unit] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  (1 to 3).map(i =>
    TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol
      .companionClass
      .declaredMethod(s"$$lessinit$$greater$$default$$$i")
      .headOption
      .flatMap(_.tree.asInstanceOf[DefDef].rhs)
  ).foreach(println)

 '{()}
}

printDefaults[Foo]
//Some(Literal(Constant(bar)))
//None
//Some(Select(Ident(Math),PI))
```

Mirrors and macros can work together:

```
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.deriving.*

trait Default[T] {
  type Out <: Tuple
  def defaults: Out
}

object Default {
  transparent inline given mkDefault[T](using 
    m: Mirror.ProductOf[T], 
    s: ValueOf[Tuple.Size[m.MirroredElemTypes]]
  ): Default[T] =
    new Default[T] {
      type Out = Tuple.Map[m.MirroredElemTypes, Option]
      def defaults = getDefaults[T](s.value).asInstanceOf[Out]
    }

  inline def getDefaults[T](inline s: Int): Tuple = ${getDefaultsImpl[T]('s)}

  def getDefaultsImpl[T](s: Expr[Int])(using Quotes, Type[T]): Expr[Tuple] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*

    val n = s.asTerm.underlying.asInstanceOf[Literal].constant.value.asInstanceOf[Int]

    val terms: List[Option[Term]] =
      (1 to n).toList.map(i =>
        TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol
          .companionClass
          .declaredMethod(s"$$lessinit$$greater$$default$$$i")
          .headOption
          .flatMap(_.tree.asInstanceOf[DefDef].rhs)
      )

    def exprOfOption[T](oet: Option[Expr[T]])(using Type[T], Quotes): Expr[Option[T]] = oet match {
      case None => Expr(None)
      case Some(et) => '{Some($et)}
    }

    val exprs: List[Option[Expr[Any]]] = terms.map(_.map(_.asExprOf[Any]))
    val exprs1: List[Expr[Option[Any]]] = exprs.map(exprOfOption)
    Expr.ofTupleFromSeq(exprs1)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val d = summon[Default[Foo]]
summon[d.Out =:= (Option[String], Option[Int], Option[Double])] // compiles
d.defaults // (Some(bar),None,Some(3.141592653589793))
```

Comment: `.asInstanceOf[DefDef].rhs` is always returning a None.

Comment: @SimãoMartins Switch on `scalacOptions += "-Yretain-trees"` in `build.sbt` and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 4):

As Dmytro suggests, information is carried in methods `<init>default$x` of the class companion object.
However, `Quotes` discourages accessing a symbol's tree in a macro:
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/main/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L3628.
Symbol's tree is lost, unless program is compiled with `-Yretain-trees`)

It is better to let the macro *evaluate* `<init>default$x`, rather than *copy* the right hand side of its definition.

One can do so by expressing `terms` as :

```scala
    val terms: List[Option[Term]] =
      (1 to n).toList.map(i =>
        TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol
          .companionClass
          .declaredMethod(s"$$lessinit$$greater$$default$$$i")
          .headOption
          .map(Select(Ref(TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.companionModule),_))
      )
```

Comment: Confirm its working. Whats the difference between `.companionModule` and `.companionClass`? Its also working using `companionModule` in both places.

Comment: `companionModule` refers to the _companion object_ (`object Foo`), while `companionClass` refers to the _class_ of this companion object ( `module class Foo$`).
Strictly speaking, methods are defined on the class, but they are also visible on the object symbol.

Comment: any idea why this might fail with

"Expected an expression. This is a partially applied Term. Try eta-expanding the term first at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$TreeMethods$.asExprOf(QuotesImpl.scala:113)

Comment: @ftucky If the case class is generic then `.map(Select(Ref(TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.companionModule),_))` should be replaced with `.map(s => Ref(TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.companionModule).select(s).appliedToTypes(TypeRepr.of[T].typeArgs))`. This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024281 https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-macro-examples/pull/33 `.flatMap(_.tree.asInstanceOf[DefDef].rhs)` was correct always.

Comment: @OlegYch Because the case class can be generic. Then `Select(Ref(TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.companionModule),_)` lacks `TypeApply` and is a partially applied Term. See the fix in my previous comment.