# Extract the default argument value in method

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I am trying to create a UI to test a scala interface. To do so, I am extracting all the declared methods from the interface using java reflection.
I am able to get the method names via

```scala
Class[MyClass].getDeclaredMethods.map(_.getName)
```

I am also able to extract all the parameter names and types via:

```scala
val paramNames = method.getParameters.map(_.getName)
val paramType = param.getParameterizedType.getTypeName
```

Now I am also trying to extract any default value of a parameter if there are any. However, I couldn't find a way to do so yet.

edit:
To add more context. I am trying to extract the default parameter value from a class method:

```scala
class X {
  def getSum(x: Int, y: Int = 10): Int = x + y
}
```

I want to identify that the method `getSum` has a parameter `y` of type `Int` that has a default value of `10`.
I have been able to extract the values `getSum`, `y`, and `Int`. But so far I haven't found a way to extract the default value of `10`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034142/how-do-i-access-default-parameter-values-via-scala-reflection

Comment: that post talks about extracting default params from a case class. I am not sure if the same can be applied to extract the default params from a method.

Comment: For the constructor of a (case) class (`<init>`) you have to deal with methods `<init>$default$N`, for a method `m` you have to deal with methods `m$default$N`.

Comment: Also you can use `shapeless.Default` https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/default.scala#L8-L34 https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/default.scala

Comment: But `shapeless.Default` works for **case** classes (and case-class-like types).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68421043/type-class-derivation-accessing-default-values (Scala 3, class param)

Answer (score 1):

### Using Java reflection

There is no notion of default value for method parameters in Java byte code.

So how does the Scala compiler represent default values at runtime? For each parameter with a default value the compiler adds a new method into the same class. The name of that synthesized method follows the pattern: `<methodName>$default$<parameterNumber>`.

In your case, the name of the method that returns the default value of `y` is `getSum$default$2`. It takes no argument and it returns `10`.

In order to get the value you need to call that method on an instance of class `X`. If you do not have an instance of `X` then you cannot get the value at runtime.

That is because, in the general case, a default value can depend on some previous parameters or even on some fields of the class.

```scala
class X(default: Int) {
  def getSum(x: Int, y: Int = default): Int = x + y
}

class Y {
  def getSum(x: Int)(y: Int = x): Int = x + y
}
```

In the first case the body of `getSum$default$2` is `this.default`. In the second case the `getSum$default$2` method  takes `x` as parameter and returns its value.

### Using Scala Compile-time Reflection (Scala 2)

Possibly you could use scala-reflect to find the `DefDef` tree of the `getSum$default$2` method. Then you may be able to get the body of the method.

See Scala 2 reflection documentation [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html).

### Using Macros (Scala 3)

You can create a macro method that returns the body of the getter method of some default value.

Here I made some experiment:

```scala
package macros

import quoted._

object Check:
  inline def defaultValue[T]: Any = ${ impl[T] }

  private def impl[T](using Quotes, Type[T]): Expr[Any] =
    import quotes.reflect.*

    val tpe = TypeRepr.of[T]
    val symbol = tpe.classSymbol
      .getOrElse(report.throwError("It is not a class"))
    
    val classTree = symbol.tree.asInstanceOf[ClassDef]
    val method = classTree.body
      .collect { case m: DefDef => m }
      .find(m => m.name == "getSum$default$2")
      .getOrElse(report.throwError("Getter method not found"))
    method.rhs.get.asExprOf[Any]
```

```scala
@main def run(): Unit =
  println(macros.Check.defaultValue[X])
```

We need to use the `-Yretain-trees` compiler option to compile that code. It should print `10`.