# How to get the list of default fields values for typed case class?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

There is a existsing macro that gets the list of default fields with their values
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-macro-examples/blob/main/defaultParamsInference/src/macro.scala
However if you try to use it to get default for typed class, an Assertion error is thrown:

```
[error]     |Exception occurred while executing macro expansion.
[error]     |java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
[error]     |   at scala.runtime.Scala3RunTime$.assertFailed(Scala3RunTime.scala:11)
[error]     |   at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$Ref$.apply(QuotesImpl.scala:435)
[error]     |   at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$Ref$.apply(QuotesImpl.scala:434)
[error]     |   at defaultParamsImpl(Decoder.scala:126)
```

How to fix it?
it is thrown in this line: `val mod  = Ref(sym.companionModule)`

Comment: Check your version, the example with 3.1+

Comment: my version is 3.1.3
For regular case classes it works fine, it doesn't work with typed ones
Nevertheless, I found the solution

Comment: Any (regular) case class is typed

Comment: @cchantep OP meant a case class with a generic

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have

```
case class B(i: Int = 1, s: String = "a")
case class A[T](i: Int = 1, s: String = "a", l: List[T] = Nil)
```

Firstly, `TypeTree.of[T].symbol` produces `class B` for `B` but `val <none>` for generic `A`. So replace `TypeTree.of[T].symbol` with `TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol`.

Secondly, for generic `A` in its companion object methods `<init>$default$N` are generic too. So you need to apply `mod.select(deff.symbol)` to type arguments (otherwise terms `mod.select(deff.symbol)` are partially applied).

The whole code:

```
import scala.annotation.experimental
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.deriving.*

inline def defaultParams[T]: Map[String, Any] = ${ defaultParmasImpl[T] }

@experimental // because .typeArgs is @experimental
def defaultParmasImpl[T](using quotes: Quotes, tpe: Type[T]): Expr[Map[String, Any]] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  val typ = TypeRepr.of[T]
  val sym = typ.typeSymbol
  val typeArgs = typ.typeArgs

  val comp = sym.companionClass
  val mod = Ref(sym.companionModule)
  val names =
    for p <- sym.caseFields if p.flags.is(Flags.HasDefault)
      yield p.name
  val namesExpr: Expr[List[String]] =
    Expr.ofList(names.map(Expr(_)))

  val body = comp.tree.asInstanceOf[ClassDef].body
  val idents: List[Term] =
    for case deff @ DefDef(name, _, _, _) <- body
    if name.startsWith("$lessinit$greater$default")
    yield mod.select(deff.symbol).appliedToTypes(typeArgs)

  val identsExpr: Expr[List[Any]] =
    Expr.ofList(idents.map(_.asExpr))

  '{ $namesExpr.zip($identsExpr).toMap }
```

Testing:

```
defaultParams[B] // Map(i -> 1, s -> a)
defaultParams[A[Double]] // Map(i -> 1, s -> a, l -> List())
```

Scala 3.1.3.

See also [Type Class Derivation accessing default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68421043/type-class-derivation-accessing-default-values)

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-macro-examples/pull/33