# Scala 3 Macros: How to invoke a method obtained as a `Symbol` in a quoted code block?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, scala-reflect, scala-quasiquotes

In a Scala 3 macro that takes a type parameter `T`, you can use `TypeRepr.of[T]` and the new [Scala 3 reflection API](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/reflection.html) to explore the `companionClass` of `T`, and find the [`Symbol`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/reflection.html#symbols) for an arbitrary method on that companion class (eg `companionClass.declarations.find(_.name == "list")` to find a `list()` method).

Given the `Symbol` for a companion object method, how would you then **invoke that method** within a [quoted code block](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/quotes.html)?

I'm guessing I would need to convert that `Symbol` to a `Expr[T]`, but I don't know how to do that!

In a Scala 2 macro, the invocation of a `listMethod` of type `c.universe.Symbol` in a `q"..."` quasiquote seems pretty simple - just say `$listMethod`, and then you can start mapping on the resulting list, eg:

```
q"""
$listMethod.map(_.toString)
 """
```

Trying to do a similar thing in a Scala 3 macro gets an error like this:

```
[error] 27 |                ${listMethod}.map(_.toString)
[error]    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |                  Found:    (listMethod : x$1.reflect.Symbol)
[error]    |                  Required: quoted.Expr[Any]
```

What is the correct code to get this working in Scala 3?

You can see more code context in the `AvroSerialisableMacro` classes (Scala 2 compiles, Scala 3 currently nowhere near!) here: https://github.com/guardian/marley/pull/77/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's talk how to call a method using symbol name in general.

You might need `Select`. You can call obtain it in a a few different ways, e.g.:

```
New(TypeTree.of[YourType]).select(primaryConstructor) // when you want to create something

expression.asTerm.select(method) // when you want to call it on something
```

Once you selected method you can provide arguments:

```
select.appliedToArgs(args)  // if there is only 1 argument list
select.appliedToArgss(args) // if there is more than one argument list
                            // (type parameter list is listed in paramSymss
                            // but shouldn't be used here, so filter it out!)
select.appliedToNone        // if this is a method like "def method(): T"
                            // (single, but empty, parameter list)
select.appliedToArgss(Nil)  // is this is a method like "def method: T"
                            // (with not even empty parameter list)
```

There are also other methods like `appliedToType`, `appliedToTypeTrees`, but if you have a method name as a `Symbol` and want to use it to call something this should be a good starting point.

And remember that source code of [`Quotes`](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/0b08074c8d75f4dd91bd5a97e3821657afbb5a3e/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala) is your friend, so even when your IDE doesn't give you any suggestions, it can point you towards some solution.

In theory these methods are defined on `Term` rather than `Select` (`<: Term`) but your use case will be most likely picking an expression and calling a method on it with some parameters. So a full example could be e.g.

```
val expression: Expr[Input]
val method:     Symbol
val args:       List[Term]

// (input: Input).method(args) : Output
expression             // Expr[Input]
  .asTerm              // Term
  .select(method)      // Select
  .appliedToArgs(args) // Term
  .asExpr              // Expr[?]
  .asExprOf[Output]    // Expr[Output]
```

Obviously, proving that the `expression` can call `method` and making sure that types of `Term`s in `args` match allowed types of values that you pass to the method, is on you. It is a bit more hassle than it was in Scala 2 since quotes allow you to work with `Type[T]` and `Expr[T]` only, so anything that doesn't fall under that category has to be implemented with macros/Tasty ADT until you get to the point that you can return `Expr` inside `${}`.

That said, the example you linked shows that these calls are rather hardcoded, so you don't have to look up `Symbol`s and call them. Your code will most likely do away with:

```
// T <: ThriftEnum

// Creating companion's Expr can be done with asExprOf called on
// Ref from Dmytro Mitin's answer
def findCompanionOfThisOrParent(): Expr[ThriftEnumObject[T]] = ...

// _Expr_ with the List value you constructed instead of Symbol!
val listOfValues: Expr[List[T]] = '{
  ${ findCompanionOfThisOrParent() }.list
}

// once you have an Expr you don't have to do any magic
// to call a method on it, Quotes works nice
'{
   ...
   val valueMap = Map(${ listOfValues }.map(x => x ->
          org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.get.createEnum(
            com.gu.marley.enumsymbols.SnakesOnACamel.toSnake(x.name), schemaInstance)
        ): _*)
   ...
}
```

Comment: It's better to replace `.asExpr.asInstanceOf[Expr[Output]]` with `.asExprOf[Output]`

Comment: Yes, I know asExprOf but I was not sure if it was something from Quotes or one of my utilities when I looked up my notes.

Comment: Either `expression` in `expression.select(method)` should be of type `Term` instead of `Expr[Input]` or this should be `expression.asTerm.select(method)`

Comment: You're right, I my mistake, thanks! I fixed this

Answer (score 2):

Difference between Scala 2 [quasiquotes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html) and Scala 3 [quotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html) is that the former must compile during compile time of the main code using macros (i.e. during macro expansion, macro runtime) while the latter must compile earlier, at macro compile time. So Scala 3 quotations `'{...}`/`${...}` are more like Scala 2 [`reify{...}`/`.splice`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-reify) than Scala 2 quasiquotes `q"..."`/`${...}`.

[`tq` equivalent in Scala 3 macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852787/tq-equivalent-in-scala-3-macros)

You have to re-create AST. Let's see what shape AST should have:

```
object B:
  def fff(): Unit = ()

import scala.quoted.*

inline def foo(): Unit = ${fooImpl}

def fooImpl(using Quotes): Expr[Unit] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  println('{B.fff()}.asTerm.show(using Printer.TreeStructure))

  '{()}
```

```
foo() // ... Apply(Select(Ident("B"), "fff"), Nil)
```

So in order to re-create AST try to use `Apply(...)` and `Select.unique(..., "list")`:

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def foo[T](): Unit = ${fooImpl[T]}

def fooImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[Unit] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val sym = TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol

  '{
    println("aaa")

    ${
      Apply(
        Select.unique(
          Ref(sym.companionModule),
          "list"
        ),
        Nil
      ).asExprOf[Unit]
    }
  }
```

Testing (in a different file):

```
class A
object A {
  def list(): Unit = println("list")
}

foo[A]()

//scalac: {
//  scala.Predef.println("aaa")
//  A.list()
//}

// prints at runtime:
// aaa
// list
```

Using method symbol rather than its name and using convenience methods rather than AST nodes directly, you can rewrite `fooImpl` as

```
def fooImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[Unit] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val sym = TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol
  val listMethod = sym.companionClass.declarations.find(_.name == "list").get

  '{
    println("aaa")

    ${
      Ref(sym.companionModule)
        .select(listMethod)
        .appliedToArgs(Nil)
        .asExprOf[Unit]
    }
  }
```

This is just an example how to create an AST. You should use your actual return type of `def list()` instead of `Unit` in `.asExprOf[Unit]`.

[How to get the list of default fields values for typed case class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024281/how-to-get-the-list-of-default-fields-values-for-typed-case-class)

[scala 3 macro how to implement generic trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561193/scala-3-macro-how-to-implement-generic-trait/)

Comment: I believe author's intended use case would require `asExprOf[List[T]]` rather than `asExprOf[Unit]` since he want to extract values from enum's companion.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Yeah, surely. This is just an example how to construct AST.